# Movie identification: post-apocalyptic setting featuring a genetically engineered forest

Tags: giniro-no-kami-no-agito

I saw this movie in 2012 on The Hub (Discovery Channel's kid network).

It takes place after an undefined apocalypse, where the earth is now mostly desert and the moon is shattered into pieces, after being destroyed due to an extremist bombing of a laboratory located there. Now all that is shown remaining on the planet is a human town bordering a jungle-like forest filled with animal-like plant monsters largely hostile to humans. The entire forest is a super-organism led by twin dryad-like beings that the people in the town treat like gods. The water supply of the planet is ever dropping, and the forest is taking most of it leaving the town dry.

Elsewhere, humanity is composed of a military-state in a partially underground base that is hostile to the forest and is also in need of water. The protagonist is a boy from the village who agrees to be turned into superpowered human-plant hybrid by the forest to fight this army, and his hair turns white and his clothing changes to being red and sleeve-less.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This sounds like "[Origin: Spirits of the Past](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Origin:_Spirits_of_the_Past)" (or Gin-iro no kami no Agito).

[image]

From the Wikipedia Link

> Genetic engineering on trees was conducted at a research facility on the Moon to produce trees capable of growing in harsh, arid conditions. The trees gain consciousness, obliterating Earth's civilizations and destroying the Moon. Three hundred years later, Japan is a dystopia covered by the Forest, a huge expanse of sapient trees, and ruled by the tree-like Zruids, which inhabit the planet and control the water supply of both trees and humans. Agito, a geeky young boy, and his father Agashi, as well as his friends Cain and Minka, live in Neutral City, a city carved out of the ruined skyscrapers which acts as both a buffer and a bridge between the Forest and the militaristic nation of Ragna. While the people of Neutral City co-exist peacefully with the trees of the forest, the nation of Ragna aims to destroy the Forest to restore the Earth.

I wasn't aware that it aired on the Discovery channel but it was made in 2006 and licensed by Funimation, and would definitely of have fit the 2012 airing time frame. The description of the movie pretty much matches.

For more info:

- [Anime News Network](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=5488)
- [Funimation page](http://www.funimation.com/origin-spirits-of-the-past)

Comment: Yep, that's it. Stupid Aesop and all!

Comment: Looks like the boy has been hanged, except he's smiling.